# Vuetable-2 not working with Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, laravel-passport, vue-tables-2

I'm working with laravel as backend (API with Passport) and i have vuetable-2 to handle data in front end. Actualy I'm configuring vuetable-2 with my customers API. First i have configure vuetable with an externa API, then i have configure laravel to work as vuetable-2 expected (format of the json response).

I have tested my api with POSTMAN and it's all working fine.

[image]

The problem started when i configure vuetable-2 with my customer API. I allways get:

> 401 Unauthorized.Unauthenticated.

I have tried adding 'auth:api' to api middleware on kernel.php but nothing change... Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with vuetable-2 and axios. Fixed:

Add to vuetable-2:

```
:http-fetch="myFetch"
```

Function:

```
myFetch(apiUrl, httpOptions) {
                return axios.get(apiUrl, httpOptions)
            }
```

Comment: can you pls elaborate a little? , coz i put the code you posted and still get the same (unauthenticated) , should i remove something from vuetable?
I had this problem after format my PC and reinstall nodejs, also my project was old  (2 years), does that effect also ?