# laravel vuejs vuetable-2 (unauthenticated)

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, laravel-passport

First
I tried all the solutions in here and others in the internet

What I have tried in here:

[Vuetable-2 not working with Laravel Passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479195/vuetable-2-not-working-with-laravel-passport)

[Unable to retrieve data from using vuetable-2, in Vuejs 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706285/unable-to-retrieve-data-from-using-vuetable-2-in-vuejs-2)

***The Problem:*** I was working on a project (Larave + VueJs) and using (passport) for laravel auth and (vuetable-2) to viewing data in table, the project was left for 2 years, And I format my PC a week ago.

Now I need to work on the project again , so installed NodeJs and called `npm install`
Also removed some (deprecated) libraries as `npm` console said, And now I got my project to work again, But the **problem** now is when vuetable-2 try to get data from controller using `api-url`, It was working flowless when I was working on project (2 years ago).
I don't know what changed now, maybe installing new NodeJs? or npm install command? or i used other command that caused something?

**Important Note:** when using axios directly using my own function , it works,

```
axios.get("/api/devices").then((data) => {
    console.log("----------------- data---------------");
    console.log(data.data);
  });
```

but when vuetable call the same url , it gives (unauthenticated)

**My Code:**

```
<vuetable
    ref="vuetable"
    api-url="/api/devices"
    :fields="fields"
    pagination-path
    :css="css.table"
    :sort-order="sortOrder"
    :multi-sort="true"
    detail-row-component="my-detail-row"
    :append-params="moreParams"
    @vuetable:cell-clicked="onCellClicked"
    @vuetable:pagination-data="onPaginationData"
></vuetable>
```

In Controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api');
}
```

**What I have tried:**

**1.**

Added this to vuetable `:http-options="{ headers: { 'x-access-token' : csrf_token } }"`

Which **csrf_tkoen** defined in (data) as `csrf_token : document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]'),`

**2.**

Changed `http-options` to `httpOptions: { headers: { Authorization: this.csrf_token } },`

Also tried to `httpOptions: {headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' ,Authorization: this.csrf_token}},`

**3.**
Adding `:http-fetch="myFetch"` to vuetable , and to methods

```
myFetch(apiUrl, httpOptions) {
            return axios.get(apiUrl, httpOptions)
},
```

But so far nothing works.

So if You can help me with this issue I'll be so thankful.

Thanks in advance

> Edit:

I compared between Vuetable-2 call (header) and axios , and found out that axios send auth parameter

```
X-XSRF-TOKEN: eyJpdiI6ImxkVmxjUkw.....
```

Although I didn't send it manually with axios

But vuetable-2 don't

maybe this means something

Comment: Did you verify that Authorization header is in fact being sent? Did you check under development chrome's console that it's present in request headers?

Comment: I checked for Auth header, its sent in manual axios call by me , but its not sent by vuetable api call , the value sent is like this ( X-XSRF-TOKEN: eyJpdiI6InIre.......)
But in vuetable call, there is no such value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution

For any one who will counter this issue
the solution for me was adding this line

```
headers:{ 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken },
```

in data() like this :

```
data() {
    headers:{ 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken },
}
```

then in vuetable add this line like this:

```
<vuetable
    :http-options="headers"
>
</vuetable>
```

hope it helps anyone

Regards